# JavaScript is not executed in tracking form

Tags: javascript, python, jquery, ajax

I'm doing an e-commerce website for school and got the task to implement an order tracking system to display the status history of the order. I used a template for this, and half of the code is working. In the views.py file I fetch the information form the database and put it in json format.
However in my html file there is a js script that is supposed to display the iformation from the database and that is not working.
I unfortunately do not have any previous experience with web development, so I'm lost as to why it doesn't work because in the video that used the template it worked.

If someone could help me that would be fantastic as we have to hand the project in in two days.

PS.:
When I put in the ref code and email, it just gives back the HttpResponse with the json. I'm not sure what to do with the HttpResponse though. How does it interact with the script in the html file?

I put

```
jQuery.noConflict();
```

at the start of the script as I thought maybe the bootstrap js was overshadowing my script. It didn't do anything though.

Here is my views.py function:

```
def tracking(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        ref_code = request.POST.get('ref_code', '')
        email = request.POST.get('email', '')
        try:
            order = Order.objects.filter(ref_code=ref_code, email=email)
            if len(order) > 0:
                update = OrderUpdate.objects.filter(ref_code=ref_code)
                updates = []
                for item in update:
                    updates.append(
                        {'text': item.update_desc, 'time': item.timestamp})
                    response = json.dumps(updates, default=str)
                return HttpResponse(response)
            else:
                return HttpResponse('Please enter a valid ref code and email address.')
        finally:
            print()
    return render(request, 'order_tracking.html')
```

Here is the script from the order_tracking html file:

```
<script>
jQuery.noConflict();
$('#trackingForm').submit(function(event) {
    $('#items').empty();
    var formData = {
        'ref_code': $('input[name=ref_code]').val(),
        'email': $('input[name=email]').val(),
        'csrfmiddlewaretoken': $('input[name=csrfmiddlewaretoken]').val()
    };
    print(ref_code)
    $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: '/order-tracking/',
            data: formData,
            encode: true
        })
        .done(function(data) {
            console.log(data)
            updates = JSON.parse(data);
            if (updates.length > 0 & updates != {}) {
                for (i = 0; i < updates.length; i++) {
                    let text = updates[i]['text'];
                    let time = updates[i]['time'];
                    mystr = `
                    <li class="list-group-item d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center">
                        ${text}
                        <span class="badge badge-primary badge-pill">${time}</span>
                    </li>`
                    $('#items').append(mystr);
                }
            } else {
                mystr = `<li class="list-group-item d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center">
                    Sorry, We are not able to fetch this ref code and email. Make sure to type correct ref code and email</li>`
                $('#items').append(mystr);
            }
        });
    event.preventDefault();
});
</script>
```

And this is the rest of the html file, I'm not sure if it's relevant:

```
{% block content %}


<div class="container tracking">
    <div class="col my-4">
        <h2> Enter Your Order ID and Email address to track your order </h2>

           <form method="post" action="#" id="trackingForm">{% csrf_token %}
            <div class="form-row">
                <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                    <label for="inputname">Ref Code</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="ref_code" name="ref_code" placeholder="Ref Code">
                </div>
                <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                    <label for="inputEmail">Email</label>
                    <input type="email" class="form-control" id="email" name="email" placeholder="Email">
                </div>
                 <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Track Order</button>
            </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col my-4">
        <h2>Your Order Status:</h2>
        <div class="my-4">
            <ul class="list-group" id="items">
            </ul>
        </div>
       
    </div>
</div>
{% endblock content %}
```